# Cropping and resizing an image results in blank image in a Phonegap application on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, canvas, drawimage

I'm writing a Phonegap application for Android and iOS that includes an option of uploading an image. The file, before uploaded needs to be cropped to a square (largest square possible from the middle of the original image). If the square width/height is over 320px, then it should also scale down to 320px.

I wrote the following javascript function that gets a data URL, scales the image down (if necessary), crops the image and places the result data URL into an img src attribute.

It works perfectly on Android, but in iOS (testing it with iPhone 4+iOS 7) - I'm getting either a black image (if I generate a JPEG) or a fully transparent image (if I generate a PNG).

```
function dataUrlToPreview(dataURL) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function(){
        var params = {};
        params.maxTargetSize = 320;
        params.orientationLandspace = img.width >= img.height;
        params.originalSquareSize = params.orientationLandspace ? img.height : img.width;
        params.cropWfromOriginal = params.orientationLandspace ? (img.width - params.originalSquareSize) / 2 : 0;
        params.cropHfromOriginal = !params.orientationLandspace ? (img.height - params.originalSquareSize) / 2 : 0;
        params.targetSize = params.originalSquareSize > params.maxTargetSize ? params.maxTargetSize : params.originalSquareSize;

        params.resizeW = 0;
        params.resizeH = 0;

        if (params.originalSquareSize > params.maxTargetSize) {
            params.resizeRatio = params.orientationLandspace ? params.maxTargetSize / img.height : params.maxTargetSize / img.width;
            params.resizeW = Math.round(img.width * params.resizeRatio);
            params.resizeH = Math.round(img.height * params.resizeRatio);
        } else {
            params.resizeW = img.width;
            params.resizeH = img.height;
        }

        var canvas = $("<canvas width=\"" + params.targetSize + "\" height=\"" + params.targetSize + "\"/>")
            .hide().appendTo("body");
        var ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext('2d');

        ctx.drawImage(img, params.cropWfromOriginal, params.cropHfromOriginal, img.width, img.height, 0, 0, params.resizeW, params.resizeH);
        var base64ImageData = canvas.get(0).toDataURL("image/jpeg");

        $("#preview").attr("src", base64ImageData);
        canvas.remove();
    }
    img.src = dataURL;
}
```

I did some testing and found that the problem doesn't happen if I don't crop the image (so if I remove the "params.cropWfromOriginal, params.cropHfromOriginal, img.width, img.height" part when calling the drawImage function).

As I mentioned, this works fine in Android and also in desktop browsers (tested on Chrome and FF).

Any thought will be appreciated here...

Thanks,
Joseph.

Comment: My guess is that it doesn't like to get non-existent pixels form the crop in the drawImage(). Could you try to do `ctx.drawImage(img, params.cropWfromOriginal, params.cropHfromOriginal, img.width-params.cropWfromOriginal, img.height-params.cropHfromOriginal, 0, 0, params.resizeW, params.resizeH);` ? Even if that would be a bug that it doesn't accept the former...

Comment: This did not do the trick. The output is still empty on iOS devices and anywhere else it just distorts the image (stretching it)... Either way, I found a viable workaround - I'm now only resizing the image and uploading it to AWS S3, where a Lambda function does the cropping...